# How to create performance point service reports or (BI) from a sharepoint list as datasource?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I need to create a report using performance point service or BI. While creating the datasource it should be from a sharepoint list and same datasource i need to use to create the report. Any suggestions?

Comment: The suite of BI tools available through sharepoint provide multiple ways to expose and manipulate data. The best solution will depend on data complexity, data sources and UI functionality.

Comment: For example, you can create a simple PowerPivot spreadsheet to use (assuming PP is configured).

Answer (score 1):

if you mean, you want to develop cube for BI datasource..

i think you need to do ETL first (using SQL Server Integration services) from SharePoint list to SQL server regular table,
then you can develop cube with sql server as datasource..

IMHO, you might consider change you app datasource from sharepoint list to regular sql server table, for performance wise